# Java seeing if list contains string

Tags: java, list, contains

I'm trying to iterate through a list line by line to check if a string the user inputs can be found and if so that line is printed. This is what i have so far

```
    while(true) {
        System.out.println("Please enter a hill name or quit to exit: ");
        String HillName = input.next();
        if (HillName.equals("quit")) {
            break;
        }
        else {
            for(int i=0; i < HillList.size(); i++) {
                if (HillList.get(i).contains(HillName)) {
                    System.out.println(HillList.get(i));
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm getting an error over contains saying cannot resolve symbol method contains java lang string, any help is appreciated.

Comment: what's the type of `HillList`? It's probably raw. In that case change it to `List<String>`.

Comment: You are checking if the hill name is in one of the strings in the list. Is that what you are intending or should each hill name correspond exactly to an entry in the list? And +1 on Eran's comment

Comment: This is an example of one entry in my HillList (255, "Ben Nevis", "Highland", 1344.5, 56.796849, -5.003525), this is where i define the HillList List<Hill> HillList = Hill.readHills(); so i haven't changed it to List<String> because it contains some ints and doubles.

Comment: Does your `Hill` class have a `contains` method? If not, that's the direct problem. Do you really mean something like `HillList.get(i).getName().contains(HillName)`?

Comment: ahh ok ill try and create a contains method in the class now if i have luck ill keep posted

Comment: try my answer with Java 8 its nice and elegant. Just check the name of the property you want to compare on. Do you know the fields of the Hill object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the reference type of the `HillList.get(i)` expression doesn't have a `contains` method. `HillList` has type `List<Hill>`, so `HillList.get(i)` has type `Hill`.

You *could* add a `contains` method to the `Hill` class; but I wouldn't expect a `Hill` to have a `contains` method - what do hills contain, other than rock, peat and the occasional hydroelectric power station? :) I certainly wouldn't expect a `contains(String)` method to return true if its name contains the parameter.

It looks like you're actually trying to print hills whose names contain some substring. For instance, if you entered `Ben`, you might print the `Hill` instances for `Ben Nevis`, `Ben Lawers`, etc. If this is the case, it looks like a much more logical check is to get the name of `HillList.get(i)`, and call `contains` on *that*, e.g.

```
if (HillList.get(i).getName().contains(HillName)) {
  // ...
}
```

You've not given a definition of the `Hill` class, so I'm assuming there's an accessor for the name like this. But it doesn't have to be like that: you could call `HillList.get(i).toString().contains(HillName)`, or something else, provided that method returns strings which contain the thing you're looking for.

---

Note that a better way to write the loop is to use an enhanced for loop:

```
for (Hill hill : HillList) {
  if (hill.getName().contains(HillName)) {
    System.out.println(hill);
  }
}
```

Repeatedly calling `HillList.get(i)` is more verbose, error-prone, and potentially less efficient if `HillList` is e.g. a `LinkedList`.

(Also note that `HillList` should be called `hillList` by convention, since variables start with lower-case letters).

Comment: Thanks man it was just a matter of toSring() and it works for the purpose i need but i'm reading everything else and just have a question with the getName() is that a method that should be defined by myself?

Comment: Yes, you can define it yourself. The second parameter of the constructor (e.g. `"Ben Nevis"`) is the name, right? And i guess you assign that to a field. Add a `getName()` method to return that field.

Comment: Or, if the field is accessible directly, you can simply refer to that, e.g. `hill.name`, forgoing the getter method. But you should understand that getter methods are generally better, as they allow more flexibility in the future.

Comment: Thanks man ill take this all on board and see what i can do, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This code will cover the case where you have your hill name in several rows of your list. Just setup $$getYourHillProperyName$$ with a getterMethod of the property you want to search.

```
     while(true) {
            System.out.println("Please enter a hill name or quit to exit: ");
            String HillName = input.next();
            if (HillName.equals("quit")) {
                break;
            }
            else {
events
.stream()
.filter(e-> e.$$getYourHillProperyName$$.contains(HillName))
.forEach(xx->System.out.println(xx));

            }
```

You don't need that "for" just use the contains as you have tried.

Comment: what is wrong with these questions ... we are answering and getting downvotes for our efforts.

Comment: Im not sure about that down votes sorry, but also with your solution what is i defined as?

Comment: The problem is that your answer is wrong. OP doesn't want to check if `HillName` is in the list. It's a list of `Hill`, not `String`, so the contains check always yields false.

Comment: the author added that later @AndyTurner

Comment: Well, even if it were not a `List<Hill>`, you are changing what the code would do. It appears the author intends to check if a part of the name matches the input. You have assumed that an equality check is equivalent, and that is not the case, so your answer is still wrong.

Comment: You are still using equals rather than contains.

Comment: @AndyTurner what do you mean? my code should work I think. what are you talking about I dont see the reason I have -2

Comment: You should test your code to the best of your ability but given the fact you switched from .Equals to .Contains indicates you understand Andys comment.

Comment: heh. How do you deal with - question - answer it first, post the answer, and meanwhile the question has changed.